# Microsoft Edge not handling AJAX response data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, cross-browser, microsoft-edge

Weird problem:

[this page](http://www.naidex.co.uk/consumer/exhibitors/) works fine on all browsers except Microsoft Edge, which fails to display the data got from an AJAX request to http://webapi.bstartup.com/api_exhibitors/3203.

If I reduce the amount of json returned then it works, but with even a moderately large amount of json returned (7Kb or so), the success function of the ajax request is not triggered.

Looking at the Edge debugger, the data IS being returned (as the size of "request body" is correct, but the error function of the ajax request is being triggered, after the timeout period which I have set to 10s.

Here is the ajax request which I think is pretty standard and is working fine in other browsers:

```
$scope.getWebApi('api_blogs/single/'+$scope.blog_id).success(function(data) {
  $scope.blog = data
  document.title = $scope.blog.blog_title
  $scope.blog.blog_content = $scope.blog.blog_content.replace(/\r\n/g,"</br>")
}).error(function() {
    console.log("error")
})
```

getWebApi is a simple wrapper:

```
NaidexApp.factory('getWebApi', function($http) {
  return {
    getWebApi: function(webApiParams,data) {
      console.log("getwebapi")
      return $http.post('http://webapi.bstartup.com/'+webApiParams,data, {timeout: 10000});
    }
  }
});
```

so I have no idea why the response is not being displayed and why the error callback is being triggered

Comment: The error callback probably passes an error object that will contain more information about what exactly goes wrong.

Comment: error is null, status is -1

Comment: Does `$scope.getWebApi` have documentation? It should be able to tell you more about that status (or how to get an actual message)

Comment: the api is on a site that I also own, it is logging that the data has been got without a problem. Also res.headersSent returns "true" on the api server.

Comment: From https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post: `-1 usually means the request was aborted, e.g. using a config.timeout.` weird. Anything in `statusText`?

Comment: I've changed it to use a standard promise, the error callback is triggered and "response" passed to the error handler is 
{config: Object {...}, data: null, status: -1, statusText: ""}

with my code now being

    $scope.getWebApi('api_blogs/single/'+$scope.blog_id).then(function(response) {
     // do some stuff if it worked
    },function(response) {
        console.log(response) // logged
    })

Comment: the edge debugger (network) shows a 200 OK response, received after 20 seconds which is the timeout in my http config, with "data received" matching the size of the json

Comment: Very strange. ---

Comment: having removed the timeout from the angular http config, it now just stays in "pending" status seemingly forever, until I guess at some point it will hit the browser limit.